# When and how do I use token and checklist cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a little problem. I just started playing MTG and in booster packs (4, 2 for each intro pack) I found two token cards (creature - 'Wolf' and artifact - 'Thopter'). Also, there was a checklist in two of them.

When and how should I use the token cards? What are the checklists for?

Comment: If you have unrelated questions, please ask them separately in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Certain cards instruct you to place tokens onto the Battlefield (e.g. [Silverfur Partisan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSilverfur%20Partisan%5d), [Aspiring Aeronaut](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAspiring%20Aeronaut%5d)). You may use token cards as those tokens, though you need not use those. Any physical object will do as long as you can clearly represent whether the token is tapped or not.

> 100.2. To play, each player needs his or her own deck of traditional Magic cards, **small items to represent any tokens** and counters, and some way to clearly track life totals.

Keep in mind that token cards are not considered cards as far as the rules are considered.

> 108.2. When a rule or text on a card refers to a “card,” it means only a Magic card. Most Magic games use only traditional Magic cards, which measure approximately 2.5 inches (6.3 cm) by 3.5 inches (8.8 cm). Certain formats also use nontraditional Magic cards, oversized cards that may have different backs. **Tokens aren’t considered cards—even a card that represents a token isn’t considered a card for rules purposes.**

This means your deck can't contain tokens.

---

Double-faced cards don't have the normal back other Magic cards have. Such cards would be identifiable in your deck, in your hand, etc.

One solution is to place your deck in truly opaque sleeves.

The other is to use a checklist card as a proxy when the double-faced card isn't on the battlefield.

Comment: Note that those are the only two ways you may have dual faced cards in a deck - 711.3 "Players must ensure that double-faced cards in hidden zones are indistinguishable from other cards in the same zone." Also the word "proxy" has a specific tournament meaning that is distinct from a checklist card